# Android One layout over another

Tags: java, android, android-layout

[image: I want to make a laout like this when I press the button on the right top]

I already designed a layout having a button on the title bar . now i want to make a layout

like in image over that layout .I heard about fragments .But it require api level 11 or more.

Any other solutions please.

Comment: What API level are you wanting to stay under?

Comment: `But it require api level 11 or more.` If you use the **support-library**, you won't have this problem.

Comment: Josef E i am using 2.3 api level (10)

Comment: check out PopupMenu class

Comment: Der Golem  can u give me a link for the supported libraaries

Comment: popup menu class need api level 11